# Prolog program - list of Peano numbers - rule returns multiple answers

Tags: prolog, logic, successor-arithmetics

I'm trying to write a Prolog program with a rule `good` which takes a list, where each term in the list is a Peano number. The rule should be true if and only if each element in the list is greater than the previous element.

For example, the following examples should be true:

```
good([]).
good([0]).
good([0,s(0)]).
good([0,s(s(0))]).
good([0,s(0),s(s(0))]).
```

And the following examples should be false:

```
good([s(0),0]).
good([0,s(0),0]).
```

Here is my code:

```
plus(X,0,X).
plus(X,s(Y),s(Z)) :- plus(X,Y,Z).

geq(X,Y) :- plus(K,Y,X).
ge(X,Y) :- geq(X,Y), not(X = Y).

good([]).
good([X]).
good([H|T]) :- good(H,T).
good(X,[H|T]) :- ge(H,X), good(T).
```

However, for the positive query `good([0,s(0),s(s(0))])`, both true and false are solutions.

What is the error?

Comment: Alternative solution : `good(L) :- msort(L,L).`

Comment: @ssBarBee: `msort/2` should be replaced by `sort/2`. Elements need to be greater only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21436321/2936460). First getting `true` and then getting `false` after backtracking, just means that it found an answer, then *at your request* tried a different path, and then couldn't find any other path to reach `true`, so returned `false`.

In other words, as that answerer says,

> The `false` response can appear inconsistent to beginning Prolog programmers and "feel" like an error or warning, but it's actually a perfectly normal Prolog response.